# Gmail SMTP Credentials: Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, smtp-auth

When I run the code on my localhost, work just perfect, I receive the email, but when I run in my web host Hostgator, doesn't work and I don't know why

code:

```
<?php

try {
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;                      // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = '*******@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = '********';                               // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
$mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom($mensagem->_get('email'), $mensagem->_get('nomear'));
$mail->addAddress('*******@gmail.com', '*********');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

// Attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = $mensagem->_get('assunto');
$mail->Body    = "O úsuario do site: <strong>{$mensagem->_get('nomear')}</strong> está entrando em contato com você pelo motivo: <strong>{$mensagem->_get('assunto')}</strong>, com a específica mensagem: <strong>{$mensagem->_get('msg')}</strong>. Responda para: {$mensagem->_get('email')}";
//$mail->AltBody = '';

$mail->send();

header('Location: obrigado.html');

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
?>
```

I already check if it's a typing error but if it were, it wouldn't work on my localhost, and I already enable the permission on my Gmail.

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question. You should write in english rather than in Portuguese.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: sorry, It's in english now

Comment: I think I can guess what's happening, but could you set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` and add the debug output to your question?

Answer (score 1):

The error message looks obvious: Your login credentials are not correct. Nonetheless, Gmail is a bit special.

Host, port, and encryption settings look okay. Maybe your password expired?

Also, try to change the password. <del>I have heard</del> credentials can get denied if Google feels they are too simple.

Generally, try to enable SMTP debugging messages

```
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

.. and check: Allow less secure apps are enabled on your Google account

> Sign in to the Google admin console/account settings,
> Go to Security > Basic settings.
> Go to Less Secure Apps. Turn on Allow less secure apps.

Comment: Have you tried to log in to the account/mailbox? Often there are Google security alerts on the account that need to be verified first. Is there a more detailed error message now?

Comment: I alredy verify and still, I will try to change the password maybe it will work

Comment: Yes, good idea. I have heard the credentials can get denied if Google feels they are too simple.